# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO] variable failing due to mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pathinfo

I'm currently trying to set up a little routing system but when I rewrite my public/index.php to just public/ my $_SERVER['PATH_INFO] variable fails to get any input.

It works fine without the .htaccess file when I visit:

**public/index.php/hello**

I get:

**Welcome! This is the main page.**

But when I rewrite to remove index.php and only leave public/ I am dead in the water.

Does anybody know a fix for this or can someone give me an explanation for it?

**Simple routing script that echoes content based on the url data that trails the script**

```
   <?php

    // First, let's define our list of routes.
    // We could put this in a different file and include it in order to separate
    // logic and configuration.
    $routes = array(
        '/'      => 'Welcome! This is the main page.',
        '/hello' => 'Hello, World!',
        '/users' => 'Users!'
    );

    // This is our router.
    function router($routes)
    {
        // Iterate through a given list of routes.
        foreach ($routes as $path => $content) {
            if ($path == $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
                // If the path matches, display its contents and stop the router.
                echo $content;
                return;
            }
        }

        // This can only be reached if none of the routes matched the path.
        echo 'Sorry! Page not found';
    }

    // Execute the router with our list of routes.
    router($routes);

    ?>
```

**My .HTACCESS file**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update #1**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you check your *AcceptPathInfo* configuration?

Comment: In your RewriteCond you are only _capturing_ the part _before_ `index.php`, and then you use that piece to rewrite to – so _you_ are discarding whatever might have been after `index.php` in the original request URI here … (And btw., I don’t really understand what the pattern `($|\ |\?)` is supposed to achieve, care to explain?)

Comment: And I’m not sure if `PATH_INFO` can even work in this scenario, because this value is whatever comes in the path after the part that could be matched to a _physically_ existent file – but exactly that physically existent file you’re trying to take out here …

Comment: And on top of that – if you are just requesting `/public/hello` now, that RewriteCond won’t even match any more … so your whole approach seems kinda messed up right now to me. Why not just match whatever comes after `public/` with a simple RewriteRule instead, and pass that as a _parameter_ to the index.php …?

Comment: To add to all of this, i am a noob when it comes to htaccess and i'm just starring to learn regex etc. I will take all comments in consideration and try to figure this out .

Comment: @CBroe the pattern `($|\ |\?)` means "end of the request line", "a space" or "the beginning of the query string". The request line looks something like: `GET /something/index.php` or `GET /something/index.php HTTP/1.1` or `GET /something/index.php?foo=bar HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Ah yeah, allright. Well, checking the full `%{THE_REQUEST}` is not a good idea anyway under most circumstances. Going with a simple RewriteRule that matches the appropriate part of the request URI as I suggested and you further explained in your answer is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a rule that tells requests like `/public/hello` to be routed to the index.php file. Apache and PATH INFO isn't smart enough to figure that out. You need to explicitly tell apache that you want a request routed to a script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've rewrote my htaccess file to this, since it is residing in my public folder. Check the update #1

It works but it doesn't pick up the slash(/) from my $routes array, any help on fixing that?

Comment: @Stephan-v not sure why you're losing the slash, your script and the htaccess file [works fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uX7S0.png)